# Combinatorics exercises

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So this is the question :

"Frogs and storks are grazing on the edge of a pond. The following happens every minute.
In the first half of the minute every frog that was there at the beginning of this minute attracts
three new frogs and one new stork. In the second half of the minute every stork eats one frog.
At the beginning there were two frogs and one stork on the edge of a pond. How many frogs
and storks are there after twenty minutes?"

I have the "formulas" for both parts of the minute:

First 30s : F = 4*F and S = F + S

Second 30s : F = F - S and S = S

I just can't seem to generelize this. Also when I did the calculation for every 30s The number of frogs that I start the previous minute is the same with the one of storks the current minute.
Thanks in prior.

Comment: @karakfa thank you very much :)

Comment: Problem.  What is the maximum number of frogs and storkes at the edge of the pond assuming it is one acre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define $F(n)$ as the number of frogs at the start of the $n^{th}$ minute and $S(n)$ as the number of storks at the start of the $n^{th}$ minute.  We are given $F(0)=2,S(0)=1$.  Now write a recurrence for $F(n+1)$ in terms of $F(n),S(n)$ and similarly for $S(n+1)$.  You have $S(n+1)=S(n)+F(n)$. What is $F(n+1)?$

Comment: is F(n + 1) = 4*F(n) - S(n + 1) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Now you have a coupled pair of recurrences.  You can just plug them into a spreadsheet or you can solve them analytically.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I really needed help on this one. Have a great life :)

Answer (score 0):

$$F_{k+\frac12}=4F_k, S_{k+\frac12}=F_k+S_k$$

$$F_{k+1}=F_{k+\frac12}-S_{k+\frac12}, S_{k+1}=S_{k+\frac12}$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
F_{k+1} &=4F_k - (F_k+S_k) \\
&= 3F_k - S_k\\
S_{k+1}&=F_k + S_k
\end{align}

Hence it is just a linear recurerrence problem.
$$\begin{bmatrix} F_{k+1} \\ S_{k+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1\\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} F_{k} \\ S_{k} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.